# Problema de css hover en dispositivos tactiles / celulares

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Nota: No es una pregunta duplicada ya que ninguna de las otras respuestas me ha servido o funcionado**

Estoy creando esta barra de navegación en CSS puro, (no tengo problema en agregar Javascript que me ayude en esto) la cual funciona bien en computadores, pero no en dispositivos táctiles como tablets o celulares.

Lo que sucede es que al hacer "hover" usando un dispositivo táctil, el código CSS para que "on hover" el background sea negro y las letras blancas, no es respetado por el navegador y hace un tipo de salto hacia el final de la categoría seleccionada.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora

```css
 #menu {
      grid-area: menu;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      text-align: left;
      border-bottom: 3px solid #121212;
      background-color: inherit;
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      z-index: 8;
    }
    .categories {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      width: 92%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      overflow: hidden;
      height: auto;
      text-align: left;
    }
    .categories a {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 42px;
      line-height: 42px;
      font-size: 1em;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-align: left;
      border-bottom: 1px dotted #121212;
    }

    .categories a:hover {
      color: #ffffff;
      background-color: #121212;
      padding-left: 25px;
    }


    .locations {
      display: none;
      position: relative;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      text-align: left;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding-left: 25px;
      padding-right: 25px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .locations a {
      display: block;
      font-size: 0.938em;
      color: #121212;
      text-transform: capitalize;
      text-align: left;
      height: 38px;
      line-height: 38px;
      border-bottom: 1px dotted #121212;
    }
    .locations a:hover {
      color: #e5633f;
      background-color: inherit;
      padding-left: 0px;
      text-transform: capitalize;
    }

    .categories .locations {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div id="menu" class="active">
      <div class="categories" open><a href="#void">News</a>
        <div class="locations">
          <a href="#">Europe</a>
          <a href="#">Asia</a>
          <a href="#">Africa</a>
          <a href="#">Oceania</a>
          <a href="#">North America</a>
          <a href="#">South America</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="categories" open><a href="#void">Education</a>
        <div class="locations">
          <a href="#">Europe</a>
          <a href="#">Asia</a>
          <a href="#">Africa</a>
          <a href="#">Oceania</a>
          <a href="#">North America</a>
          <a href="#">South America</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>
```

He probado usando lo siguiente, desde otras respuestas a preguntas similares, pero ninguna funciona:

```css
cursor:pointer
hover:active
hover:focus
css media queries hover:hover 
pointer: fine
```

He creado un Codepen para ver la barra de navegación en tiempo real y jugar con el código:

https://codepen.io/familias/pen/XWygWzY

Para ver el error/bug/problema al que me refiero, comienza haciendo hover desde arriba hacia abajo por las categorías, luego haz lo mismo pero al revés y veras a lo que me refiero.

Comment: No hace nada raro, funciona como debe. Cuando el cursor está encima de una categoría, la nueva sección se abre y ocupa el espacio libre de la sección anterior. Si quieres un movimiento suave, usa la propiedad CSS `transition-duration`. Un ejemplo en https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-duration

Comment: claro pero los celulares no tienen cursor, por eso el problema es en dispositivos táctiles

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427447/does-css-hover-work-on-mobile-devices) para entender por qué hover no tiene sentido en dispositivos táctiles.

Answer (score 0):

¿Si usas `:focus` ó `:active` en lugar de `:hover` no lo corrige?

Y después puedes usar un media query hover para saber si estas en dispositivos que aceptan hover y así condicionarlo.

```css
@media (hover: hover) {
  // Acepta hover
}

@media (hover: none) {
  // No acepta hover
}
```

Como quiera que sea solo padding puede estar afectando la posición del elemento. Prueba quitarlo o usar `box-sizing: border-box` para que no se modifique el espacio que abarca el padding.